# How to stop Google Photos from launching at system startup?

Tags: google-photos

Google Photos starts every time I turn on my Macbook Pro. It is annoying and I believe it slows down the OS' startup speed. Is there a way to turn the launch at startup option off? I do not see it in Google Photos' preferences. It seems the only option is to uninstall it:

[image]

Comment: is it listed in System Prefs > Users & Groups > [yourname] > Login Items? If so, select & hit the minus sign - underneath.

Comment: Sorry @DylanChensky, i dind't see this comment, i'll delete my answer. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hope that Tetsujin put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's listed in System Prefs > Users & Groups > [yourname] > Login Items,
select & hit the minus sign  <kbd>-</kbd>   underneath.